# Top-level await does not work with Parcel

Tags: javascript, asynchronous, parcel

Top level `await` works correctly when I run it in live server plugin (or *edit live* Webstorm IDE); however, that code throws an error when I deploy it with `npx parcel index.html`.

> Uncaught SyntaxError: await is only valid in async functions and the top level bodies of modules

```js
const res =  await Promise.resolve('hi there');

console.log(res)
```

```html
<!DOCTYPE html>
<html lang="en">
  <head>
    <meta charset="UTF-8" />
    <meta name="viewport" content="width=device-width, initial-scale=1.0" />
    <meta http-equiv="X-UA-Compatible" content="ie=edge" />
    <script type="module" defer src="script.js"></script>
    <title>parcel and top-level-await</title>
  </head>
  <body>
  </body>
</html>
```

```
   {
  "devDependencies": {
    "parcel": "^2.2.1"
  },
  "name": "top-level-await",
  "version": "1.0.0",
  "main": "index.js",
  "author": "elmi-elmi",
  "license": "MIT"
}
```

Comment: @Terry - [Top-level await is broadly supported by modern browsers](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Operators/await#browser_compatibility).

Comment: By default, Parcel bundles your code into a single *script* (not a module), but top-level `await` can only be used in modules, so it doesn't work. You have to tell Parcel to output a module file instead. There seems to be an [`outputFormat`](https://parceljs.org/features/targets/#outputformat) option for controlling it, but I don't use Parcel and didn't get it working in the few minutes of fiddling I did. There's also [this open issue](https://github.com/parcel-bundler/parcel/issues/4028) about TLA.

Answer (score -1, accepted):

I found the answer after reading Parcel [Doc](https://parceljs.org/docs/).

1. Read [here](https://parceljs.org/getting-started/migration/#%3Cscript-type%3D%22module%22%3E). Use a `<script type="module">` element to reference a module.
2. Remove the `dist` folder if it exists, then use these commands:

   ```
   npx parcel build index.html
   npx parcel index.html
   ```

---

Or set up a script to build your app. You can read [here](https://parceljs.org/getting-started/webapp/#package-scripts).

> So far, we’ve been running the parcel CLI directly, but it can be useful to create some scripts in your `package.json` file to make this easier.

```json
{
  "name": "my-project",
  "source": "src/index.html",
  "scripts": {
    "start": "parcel",
    "build": "parcel build"
  },
  "devDependencies": {
    "parcel": "latest"
  }
}
```

Now use these commands:

npm:

```
npm run build
npm run start
```

yarn:

```
yarn build
yarn start
```

```js
const res = await Promise.resolve('hi there');

console.log(res)
```

```html
<!DOCTYPE html>
<html lang="en">
  <head>
    <meta charset="UTF-8" />
    <meta name="viewport" content="width=device-width, initial-scale=1.0" />
    <meta http-equiv="X-UA-Compatible" content="ie=edge" />
    <script type="module" defer src="script.js"></script>
    <title>parcel and top-level-await</title>
  </head>
  <body>
  </body>
</html>
```